# bash statement devpath=$(command -v $bin)

Tags: bash

From a third party bash script, I have code like

```
devpath="$(command -v $bin)"
devpath="$(type -p $bin)"
```

Can you please tell what does it mean?

Comment: Which part of it don't you understand? The `$(...)` notation, or what `command -v $bin` and `type -p $bin` do?

Comment: `$(...)` is basic shell syntax that any `bash` programmer should know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means... run `command -v` with argument `$bin` and save the output in the variable `devpath`. the other command is similar... run `type -v $bin` and save the output in `devpath`.

Answer (score 0):

As a result of running this code, `devpath` will contain output of the command (i.e. `command -v $bin`).

This Bash behaviour is called "command substitution" and is described in [section 3.5.4](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution) of the Bash reference manual as follows:

> Command substitution allows the output of a command to replace the
>   command itself. (...) Bash performs the expansion by executing command
>   and replacing the command substitution with the standard output of the
>   command, with any trailing newlines deleted. (...) If the substitution
>   appears within double quotes, word splitting and filename expansion
>   are not performed on the results.

For instance this script (saved as `a.sh`):

```
devpath="$(ls -al)"

while read -r line; do
        echo "Line: ${line}"
done <<< "$devpath"
```

When invoked in a directory with three files, "a.txt", "b.txt" and "c.txt", could print out something like:

```
Line: total 8
Line: drwxr-xr-x    6 kls  staff   204 Feb  9 07:39 .
Line: drwxr-xr-x+ 106 kls  staff  3604 Feb  9 07:38 ..
Line: -rwxr-xr-x    1 kls  staff    86 Feb  9 07:38 a.sh
Line: -rw-r--r--    1 kls  staff     0 Feb  9 07:39 a.txt
Line: -rw-r--r--    1 kls  staff     0 Feb  9 07:39 b.txt
Line: -rw-r--r--    1 kls  staff     0 Feb  9 07:39 c.txt
```